# (@Context HttpServletResponse response not work in resteasy

Tags: java, servlets, web

Web application with resteasy framework.

```
@Path("/do3")
@GET
public void response(@Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{ 
    response.setStatus(202);

}
```

why get /do3 return 204, not 202? Thanks in advance.

PS: (1) I switch to @post method. it also can't get expected code: 202 by get.
(2) response.addHeader("key", "value");  can work normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RESTEasy is interpreting your method as best it can - you didn't specify a return type so it returns a 204 (No Content) back to the client. A void `GET` method really does not make alot of sense and should be avoided, or converted into another HTTP verb (like POST).

On topic, this is not the right way to set the status of responses from JAX-RS calls. You should use the [ResponseBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) instead.

```
Response.status(202).build();
```

You can of course, use the injected `HttpServletResponse` for any other thing as long as it makes sense within the context of the call:

```
response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com/myresource/5");
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the injected HttpServletResponse can't set status code in resteasy  but other features work rightly?

Comment: He means that RESTEasy is working right; you should set status codes by returning a `Response` object.

Comment: The answer to this " Do you mean the injected HttpServletResponse can't set status code in resteasy but other features work rightly?" is basically yes.  You are allowed to set header values, but changing the status code will not work.

Comment: That's a pity because if I want to use my JAX-RS attonated java interface for a proxy client I cannot return Response